# why this condition is always False

Tags: python

my code :

```
def isModuleBlink(modulename):
f = '/tmp/'+modulename + '.blink'
if(os.path.isfile(f)):
    with open(f) as fii:
        res = fii.read()
    print 'res',res
    print res is '1'
    if(res is '1'):
        print 'return true'
        return True
return False
```

and print out :

```
res 1

False
```

Why python return false for condition?

When I test `print '1' is '1'` in python terminal terunt `true` but in this script return False?

Comment: read up on the difference between `==` and `is`

Comment: `'1' is '1'` is allowed to be either `True` or `False` depending on if both `'1'` are interned to the same object or not. Use `==` for string equality.

Comment: @DanD. Same Result with `==` ...

Answer (score 1):

`res` is `1 \n` and not `1` ... in condition i replaced `1 in res` and work ...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

`is` tests if things are *identical*. You want to test if two strings are equal, not necessarily that they occupy the same memory address. So you want `==`.

Comment: `res` is the return value from `file.read`, so it's a `str`, not an `int`.

Comment: `res` is `string` ....
`print 'res',res
        print 'type of res',type(res)
        print res is '1'`
print out :
`res 0

type of res <type 'str'>
False
`

Comment: same result with `==` ...!?